# Hibernate criteria - one side mapped, criteria from other side

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a question.

I have class A:

```
public class A {
    mapped id
    mapped name
}
```

and class B:

```
public class B {
    mapped @OneToMany List<A>
    mapped name
}
```

How can I create criteria, that is created on class "A", and get their associated class "B"?

Comment: in class A create an field of class B and annotate it with `@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "id_of_B")`

Comment: there is no way to avoid it? cause i have simple lightweight objects created, and don't want to edit all the code

Comment: there is no other way. any annotation must be on a field or getter/setter

Comment: you could use the old style join if you were to use hql query instead of criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity:

```
public class A {
    mapped id
    mapped name
    @ManyToOne B b;
}

public class B {
    mapped @OneToMany(mappedBy="b") List<A>
    mapped name
}
```

There is another solution with HQL, but i don't want to use it;